# Compiling & Instaling web services separately

Tags: java, soap, jde

in our company we have to much Web Services created in the same proyect, and the time that we need to waste compiling the proyect is too big, so I was wondering if we can compile & install them separately.

We are working with JDE 9.0

*Sorry for my english level, I'm working on it*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've ran into the same issue.  It's up to the developers to determine a long-term approach and then propose to management the plan to be break the code base into logical functional projects **to help improve productivity**. Attempt to quantify the benefit such as local build time will decrease by x%.

To minimize risk plan for multiple iterations/release cycles.  For example:

**iteration 0**

1) Break one project off from the monolothic project into it's own project

2) The final deployed WAR still includes the now separate project (as a jar) so everything is still deployed together.

*repeat above for each project*

**iteration N**

Deploy the separated projects as their own WAR.  Depending on your company, this step might involve people other than the developers.

Comment: Apparently in the local testing environment works fine, we have not taken it to DV yet, but it looks good, thank you!